# How to delete elements by key in map, which contains char and pair<int,string>

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I want to delete all elements which pair first == 0

Here code:

```
int main()
{
    map<char, pair<int,string>> myMap;
    map<char, pair<int,string>>::const_iterator it;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        char c = 'a' + i;
        pair<int,string> p = make_pair(rand() % 2, "dd");
        myMap.insert(make_pair(c,p));
    }

    it = find_if(myMap.begin, myMap.end(), isEqual);

}

bool isEqual(const pair<char, pair<int, string> > element)
{
    return element.second.first == 0;
}
```

Error:

> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:150: error: could not convert
>   '`__first.std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>::operator*<std::pair<const char,
>   std::pair<int, std::basic_string<char> > > >()`' from '`std::pair<const
>   char, std::pair<int, std::basic_string<char> > >`' to '`std::pair<int,
>   std::basic_string<char> >`'
>
> ```
>    while (__first != __last && !bool(__pred(*__first)))
> ```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any deletion in your code. It just calls `find_if`, but doesn't do anything with the result.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the error in gcc 3.3, 4.8 or VS 2010.

Comment: Which compiler and version of same are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course.

I think I'd write the code something like this (I've added a bit of extra code to print out the contents of the map before and after the deletion to show that it worked):

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, pair<int, string> const &p) {
    return os << "[" << p.first << ", " << p.second << "]";
}

int main() {
    map<char, pair<int, string>> myMap;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char c = 'a' + i;
        pair<int, string> p = make_pair(rand() % 2, "dd");
        myMap.insert(make_pair(c, p));
    }

    std::cout << "before:\n";
    for (auto const &p : myMap)
        std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << "\n";

    map<char, pair<int, string> >::iterator it;
    while (myMap.end() != (it = find_if(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), [](auto p) { return p.second.first == 0; })))
        myMap.erase(it);

    std::cout << "\nafter\n\n";
    for (auto const &p : myMap)
        std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << "\n";

}
```

Comment: `error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
         std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << "\n";`

Comment: and in line while.. `note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided`

Comment: I don't see how you'd get that error unless you modified the code. Oh, as it stands it requires C++14 though (for C++11, the lambda parameter needs an explicit type instead of `auto`). [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3e7d967512ff093).

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a simple loop. You need to remember to keep track of the iterator when you erase an element from the map:

```
#include <map>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));

    std::map<char, std::pair<int, std::string>> myMap;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        char c = 'a' + i;
        auto p = std::make_pair(rand() % 2, "dd");
        myMap.insert(std::make_pair(c, p));
    }

    std::cout << "\nbefore:\n";

    for(auto const& p: myMap)
    {
        std::cout << p.first;
        std::cout << " {" << p.second.first;
        std::cout << ", " << p.second.second;
        std::cout << "}" << '\n';
    }

    // remove items in a simple loop
    for(auto iter = myMap.begin(); iter != myMap.end();)
    {
        if(iter->second.first == 0)
            iter = myMap.erase(iter); // grab new iterator when erasing
        else
            ++iter; // otherwise just increment
    }

    std::cout << "\nafter:\n";

    for(auto const& p: myMap)
    {
        std::cout << p.first;
        std::cout << " {" << p.second.first;
        std::cout << ", " << p.second.second;
        std::cout << "}" << '\n';
    }

}
```

**Example Output:**

```
before:
a {0, dd}
b {1, dd}
c {0, dd}
d {0, dd}
e {1, dd}
f {0, dd}
g {0, dd}
h {1, dd}
i {0, dd}
j {0, dd}

after:
b {1, dd}
e {1, dd}
h {1, dd}
```